# Failed to connect python and MySQL using Docker Compose

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am trying to connect to MySQL database using Docker Compose and I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 268, in _open_connection
|     self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
| _mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.22.0.2:3306' (110)
|
| The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
| Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "//script.py", line 19, in <module>
|     cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host='172.22.0.2', user='user', password='pass', database='db', port=3306)
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/pooling.py", line 286, in connect
|     return CMySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 101, in __init__
|     self.connect(**kwargs)
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 1108, in connect
|     self._open_connection()
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 273, in _open_connection..
|     raise get_mysql_exception(mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.22.0.2:3306'
```

In my programm I have to containers: for python script and for MySQL database. Both containers are built successfully and db container starts just fine.

172.22.0.2 stands for ip address in network I've created (see docker-compose).

My python script simply connects to the database using mysql-connector.

The code is the following

Dockerfile for script

```
FROM python:3.9

COPY script.py script.py
RUN pip install mysql-connector-python
```

script.py

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host='172.22.0.2', user='user', password='pass', database='db', port=3306)
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: db
    command: '--init-file /data/app/init.sql'
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - "./init.sql:/data/app/init.sql"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "db"
      MYSQL_USER: "user"
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: "pass"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "pass"
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 172.22.0.2
  script:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
    container_name: script
    command: sh -c "sleep 10s ; python script.py"
    networks:
      net:
        ipv4_address: 172.22.0.3

networks:
  net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.22.0.0/24
        gateway: 172.22.0.1
```

init.sql

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXIST db;
USE db;
```

Comment: Try to expose the ip also in ports:
```
ports:
      - 172.22.0.2:3306:3306
``` or set the host to db `host='db'` when connecting

Comment: @TelinovDmitri I get the following error after changing `ports`
`ERROR: for db  Cannot start service db: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint db : Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 172.22.0.2:3306: bind: cannot assign requested address `

Comment: Seems that this is known problem https://forums.docker.com/t/bind-cannot-assign-requested-address/12230/6

Comment: The `links:` option is obsolete, and you should be able to safely remove it.  It activates an archaic Docker networking mode; is that possibly related to this issue?

Comment: (I'd also suggest deleting _all_ of the `networks:` blocks in the entire file; let Compose create a network named `default` and let Docker assign the container-private IP addresses on its own.  The database Compose service name `db` will be usable as a host name, without needing to directly know its IP address.)